# Scaling the width/area of a violin plot according to the log(count) instead of the count

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

I would need your help, it's been 2 days that I try to finalize a plot for my research.

I currently have a series of distributions that I represent on a violin plot via sns.violinplot(). Through this function, I can normalize each violin to its count (scale='count'), equivalent width (scale='width'), or equivalent area (scale='area').

However, I need to show the differences in occurrence of each of my distributions. So I wanted to use the "count" option. But I have too big differences between the distributions and half of my distributions disappear because they are so small. Is it possible to normalize my violins plot to the log(count) instead of the count?

I have quickly written a small example with 3 distributions that I would like to normalize to log(count) rather than count.

You will save me if you can help me !

Cheers,
Bast

Here is an example of the kind of distribution I have. As you can see, the distribution with N=100 and N=500 are almost invisible. I believe scaling it according to log(count) instead of count would do the job for what I need to show.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(123)

# Generate data for three distributions
data_100 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
data_500 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 500)
data_1000 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
data_5000 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 5000)

# Create a list to hold the data
data = [data_100, data_500, data_1000, data_5000]

# Create a figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Create the violin plot
sns.violinplot(data=data, ax=ax, scale='count', cut=0)

# Set the y-axis label
ax.set_ylabel('Value')

# Set the x-tick labels
ax.set_xticklabels([100, 500, 1000, 5000])

# Set the x-axis label
ax.set_xlabel('Number of Data Points')

# Set the title
ax.set_title('Violin Plot with Count-Normalized Scale')


# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

I tried to play with my small example with chatGPT in order to find this but I couldn't... I gave up eventually and came here for you help.

Comment: You could create a new dataset, taking random samples via `np.random.choice(..., size=..., replace=True)` with sizes proportionally to the log counts.

Comment: I gave it a try. The only thing is that I don't have enough data for most of my distributions to do so. For example, it's important to me to know where the farthest point is from a distribution, and it's very likely that some of them drop while doing so...

Comment: You could multiply all sizes with the same constant.

Comment: Oh indeed, it works perfectly. That's a pretty clever way to do it. Thank you very much!